# Can't grant others write access to my via open() created file

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, file-io, permissions

I am creating a file on linux using open()

```
mode_t perms = S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH;
int i = open(settingsPath.c_str(), O_CREAT | O_RDWR, perms);
```

As you can see I am specifiying Read/Write permissions for everyone.
But when I inspect the permissions in a terminal it says

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 tstadler tstadler    0 Apr 17 10:54 settings.json
```

Why can't I give everyone write permissions?

Comment: Delete settings.json file and run your program agin

Comment: already did that of course..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like write permissions to everyone are masked by current process' `umask`.
See [man 2 umask](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html)

Comment: Can you give an example how I should use it here?

Comment: Just call `umask(0);` before `open()`.